# Pass enum 'field' via reflection in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection, enums

In Kotlin, it's easy to pass a property as a `KProperty` or `KProperty1` like this for example:

```
inline fun <TRet, reified TOwner> getName(property: KProperty1<TOwner, TRet>): String {
    return "${TOwner::class.simpleName}.${property.name}"
}
```

And then given the following type:

```
class Example(val exampleName: String)
```

I could call `getName(Example::exampleName)` which would return `Example.exampleName`.

Is there any way to do this with enums?

Say I had the following enum class:

```
enum class ExampleEnum { VALUE1, VALUE2 }
```

Is there any way to get `ExampleEnum::VALUE1` or some useful reflection object about the values in `ExampleEnum`? I essentially want to be able to access the declaring `KClass` (or java class) and the field being accessed in the enum, just by passing one argument.

The alternative is to write something like `getName(ExampleEnum::class, "VALUE1")` which is verbose and doesn't play well with refactorings/renames. Also, please note the `getName` is just an example, the actual use case is a bit more general.

Comment: Enum values are singletons, so what about passing just `ExampleEnum.VALUE1`?

Comment: @broot That would pass the value of VALUE1 - I cannot recover the name from this value.

Comment: Oh wait of course I can just toString it to get the name haha - thanks!

Comment: Every enum has `name` field, no need to use `toString()`.